# Javascript: onBeforeUnload() behaviour in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, dom-events

I have this piece of code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
      doSomething();
      return "Are you sure you want to leave";
}
```

In Firefox when user leaves the page, `doSomething()` gets executed first and then the alert pops up.
where as in IE and Chrome the alert pops up first and then if the user decides to stay `doSomething()`
gets executed.

Is there a way to make IE and Chrome behave like Firefox. I want to execute `doSomething()` before showing the pop up.

Comment: At my work we do this: `if(hasChanges && confirm('do you want to save?')) { saveToDb(); };`, which I know isn't the same example, but try using changing the last line to `return confirm("Are you sure you want to leave")`.

Comment: BTW: http://jsfiddle.net/whd9y/ works the same on all browsers (IE/FF/GC) on my pc.

Comment: @Alxandr ::  http://jsfiddle.net/whd9y/1/  try this in IE and FF. In IE it will not change the div's html until user chooses to stay on the same page.

Comment: That's just the GUI not showing the update until you close the popup. The GUI-thread is blocked, thus it can't show the changes.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Firefox are you using? As far as I know none of the browsers are supposed to let you do anything on onBeforeUnload other than pass text to be included in the confirm dialog that pops up - so you can't prevent the user from leaving your site.

You shouldn't rely on this event to ensure anything happens when the user leaves your page. If it's that important assign a click event handler to everything that can navigate away from your page (you'll still lose out on the browser navigate buttons and address bar changes)

Comment: this event works fine in most browsers. I have used it with ajax to make db changes (ofcourse using Synchronous mode) and it works exactly as it should. In the case where you want to make some HTML changes to catch user's attention apart from the alert window it has different behaviour.

Comment: in case of ajax request it doesnt matter when the call fires as long as you get your db save.

Comment: The only thing you can't do is to send XHRs as far as I know. Your comment about adding click handlers to everything is very naive. The user can close the browser, hit the back button, hit refresh. Overall no good information in this answer

Comment: @Juan Mendes thanks for such keen interest in my answer, and feedback is appreciated, but I disagree my comment is naive when I explicitly identified the drawbacks you highlighted. My aim was to point out "You shouldn't rely on this event to ensure anything happens when the user leaves your page" as onBeforeUnload has signifncant limitations. I think I did this quite clearly. Also, your comment on not sending XHRs seems to directly contradict what user425575 says they have successfully done in the preceeding comment. tl;dr - pay more attention?

Comment: @tomfumb: This is not my experience. Sending XHRs does not work reliably across browsers. I remember it worked in some but not on Safari, so we appended an img to the DOM which caused a request to go out, but I expect Safari already fixed that hole. However, I store information into cookies and modify the DOM from onbeforeunload handler with no problems cross browser.